# How do i acess multilevel json value from this json ?fr eg:in this json access menu from dish_description

Tags: android, json, multi-level

```
   [
  {
    "vendor_name": "Chef Neha Jain",
    "vendor_avatar": "http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/dear_god.jpg",
    "vendor_type": "indivisual",
    "vendor_rating": "0",
    "vendor_phone": "9875463210",
    "vendor_address": "Golf Course Road Sector 54 New Vatika Towers Gurgaon",
    "vendor_neighbourhood": "Sector 54",
    "vendor_city": "gurgaon",
    "dish_id": "2",
    "dish_name": "Dal Baati Churma Thali",
    "dish_image": "http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-779583297639/Dish%2FImages%2FDal+Baati+Churma+Thali%2FNormal%2Fdal_baati_churma_thali-hdpi.jpg",
    "dish_description": "{\"main\":\"Dine in on a grand feast of authentic cuisine from Rajasthan. Panchmel Dal, Baati, Churma, Tadka Kadhi, Lehsun Chutney, Jeera Rice all come together to create a culinary memory that you would have seldom experience before.\",\"other\":\"Served as Panchmel Dal, 2 Baatis, Churma, Tadka Kadhi, Lehsun Chutney and Jeera Rice\"}",
    "dish_palate": "[\"2\",\"4\"]",
    "dish_tags": "Baati,Daal",
    "dish_cost": "200",
    "dish_price": "250",
    "dish_rating": "4.5",
    "$$hashKey": "object:7"
  }
]
```

Comment: Man you should at least search? If you are new to android development then learn [JSON Parsing](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/)

Comment: And there are many questions/answers already exists on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Yes i did search,but i am confused on accessing the main tag inside dish description since the parenthesis is inside the quotes.Can anybody help me here?

Comment: If you don't want to manually parse and if your JSON is fixed then use `GSON` library! With that you just need to define the POJO class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below way to parse json response, If you are getting response in string otherwise remove JSONArray array = new JSONArray("res") line if getting json array.

```
try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray("res");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        String vendor_name = jsonObject.getString("vendor_name");// same way parse all string


                        if(jsonObject.has("dish_description")){

                        String dish = jsonObject.getString("dish_description");

                        dish = dish.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");

                        JSONObject  jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(dish);

                        String  main = jsonObject2.getString("main");// same way get other one 


                        }


                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: how do i access the main tag of dish description?since the parenthesis is inside quotes

Comment: You can get it into String as I mentioned and now its up to you how to use that string.

Comment: Is there any other way other than string editing?,coz i am looking for nested multilevel tags,but i cannot use them due to nesting parenthesis of "dish_description" being included inside its string field!!

Comment: you can do editing with your string but it is necessary to get it into string

Comment: what is your requirement ?

Comment: My requirement is to know and point all the field tags of dish_description,since the number of fields in it are dynamic.Anyways,thanks for the help..:)

Comment: you can do one take it into string then convert it into jsonObject

Comment: before parsing to jsonObject remove all  \ with empty space.

Comment: know check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much...:)..made some edits though